# Rules for touch gestures. Differentiate between swipe and touch event

Tags: xamarin, touch, xamarin.android

I am developing a cross platform application with Xamarin.

Currently I'm using Android's MotionEventActions (.Down/.Up and .Move) to get a dx and dy of the user's touch events. Using the dx, dy values I can then see if the user swiped or just tapped the screen. I have experimented a bit and so far I think I have pretty good thresholds, but they are not perfect.

Here is part of the code

```
        if (MyDirection == SwipeDirection.Down      && dy > 25) 
        {
            //swipe down: do something
        }

        if (Direction == SwipeDirection.Up && dy <- 25) 
        {

            //swipe up: do something 
        }
        if ((dy<5 && dy>-5) && (dx<5 && dx>-5)) 
        {
            //tap: do something
        }
```

Clearly this is not groundbreaking stuff and I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Does anyone perhaps know of the "real" thresholds used natively? Perhaps there are some more universal values I can use? Maybe there is a better way?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should instead use a `GestureDetector` alongside with `SimpleGestureListener`.
`GestureDetector` ,as its name implies, detects gestures, like `fling`, `scroll`, `tap` and so on.

You can read more on gestures in Android [here](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/index.html)